# A couple of errors i can't understand

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

So i have written this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

int main() {
    float balance;
    char type;

    printf("Card balance: ");
    scanf("%f", &balance);

    do {
        printf("Vehicle type: ");
        scanf("%c", &type);
        if (type != 'B' || type != 'b' || type != 'C' || type != 'c' || type != 'T' || type != 't') {
            printf("Incorrect vehicle type!");
        }
    } while(type != 'B' || type != 'b' || type != 'C' || type != 'c' || type != 'T' || type != 't') ;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

And when i try to run it those errors come up:

> 1.`scanf`: This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use
>   `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`.
>
> 2.system undefined; assuming extern returning int

Comment: See [the documentation for system](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx) to find out what header file to include.

Comment: You need `#include <stdlib.h>`.  The first warning is MS peddling vendor lockin, you can ignore it

Comment: `while(type != 'B' || type != 'b'  ...)` will always be true as `type` will always  compare not equal to at least 1 of `B`, `b`,

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` takes the address of a variable as argument. So, you need to do

```
scanf("%f", &balance);
scanf("%c", &type);
```

For `system`, you need to include `stdlib.h`

Comment: yeah i noticed that myself too but the rest errors?

Comment: More changes are required because the `scanf("%c"` will collect the Enter key pressed after entering the balance

Answer (score 1):

The first problem indicates that you need to give the address of the variable, or the pointer to the variable you want the scanf to return its results. Try this instead:

```
scanf("%f", &balance);
```

Edit: missing & character :)

Answer (score 0):

1) when calling `scanf()` and family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

2) the '"%f" format specifier will leave the `newline` ('\n') character in the input stream.  Then the "%c" format specifier will be reading the newline ('\n') on the first iteration and every odd iteration of the loop.

3)  the posted code is (effectively) saying `!(type==B and type==b and type==c ...)   But a variable can only hold one value at a time.  so the posted code will not properly loop. Suggest something like:

```
    do {
        ...
        if( 1 != scanf(" %c", &type) ) { // handle error }
        if (type != 'B' && type != 'b' && type != 'C' && type != 'c' && type != 'T' && type != 't') {
            printf("Incorrect vehicle type!");
        }

    } while(type != 'B' && type != 'b' && type != 'C' && type != 'c' && type != 'T' && type != 't') ;
```

Note the leading space in the format string for the call to `scanf()`, which will consume leading white space.

Note the checking of the returned value from `scanf()` to assure the operation was successful.

Note the leading `&` on the `type` parameter, as `scanf()` requires the address of its' parameters, so it will know where to place the result of the input/conversion operations.

4) `system("pause");` is not portable as not all OSs recognize the "pause" as a valid command line input.  suggest using:

```
while( int ch =getchar() && ch != '\n' && ch != EOF );
getchar();
```